# Can't run mocha tests with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, redux, mocha.js, create-react-app

I am trying to run tests using mocha for my **create-react-application** generated react/redux application.But I am getting this error:

```
import leaveReducer from '../reducers/leave.reducer.js'                                                          

^^^^^^                                                                                                           


SyntaxError: Unexpected token import                                                                             
   at createScript (vm.js:80:10)                                                                                
   at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)                                                                    
   at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)                                                                        
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)                                                          
   at Module.load (module.js:573:32)                                                                            
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)                                                                          
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)                                                                   
   at Module.require (module.js:604:17)                                                                         
   at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

I can't write ES6 syntax in my test.I think i am missing some kind of configurations to be done to the application.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your package.json file or .babelrc as

```js
scripts: {
  "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require babel-register 'PATH TO YOUR TEST DIR OR FILE' "
  }
```

Comment: @neymarsabin, please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: not working for me, does this require .babelrc as well?